# why it is hard to implement iterable cursors in async calls?

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, pymongo, nonblocking

Sorry for this dumb question, but from [this subject](https://groups.google.com/group/python-tornado/browse_thread/thread/ce583d5d4e3f13bf?hl=fr) i feel like implementing iterable cursors is difficult when dealing with non-blocking database calls,

So why is it so, and why it differs from [Pymongo cursors](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/cursor.py) ;
in other words, why cant put the [next method](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/cursor.py#L795) in non-blocking mongodb libraries?

And does this affects `find()` methods, even there is no `next()` method in [MongoTor](https://github.com/marcelnicolay/mongotor/blob/master/mongotor/cursor.py) for example, but there is still `limit()` and `skip()` , isent an iteration when limiting and continue?

here is a related topic about this on [tornado groups](https://groups.google.com/group/python-tornado/browse_thread/thread/ce583d5d4e3f13bf?hl=fr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the Python drivers, but you can't get a `next` method that returns a document because non-blocking drivers can only return future results.

MongoDB gives batches of documents. It means that when you have consumed a whole batch, you may fetch the next one. The non-blocking way of doing this is to return a future batch of documents.

There are different ways to design nicer APIs. Among them is the Iteratee/Enumerator pattern - this is the case in [ReactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org/), a non-blocking, reactive Scala driver for MongoDB.

Comment: am sorry, but what do you mean by future results?

Comment: When you deal with asynchronous results, you never get them right now without blocking. For example, if you fetch more documents from MongoDB, you have to wait for a response. Meanwhile, if you work in a non-blocking way, you get a Future -- that's like a box that may eventually contain a result, when available.

Comment: and i guess this 'box' will contain lot of results so it's like a packet? then the limit() is to limit the size of this packet? so why then not using a hidden limit(1).skip(1) as cursor.next() ?

Comment: In the case of a MongoDB batch, yes it is like a packet. Yet the limit() should not be the limit of this particular packet, but the maximum number of documents for the whole response.

Comment: am a beginner, so sorry for my bizarre answering, because i understand here that in non-blocking, the result is unpredictable to not make a size to split this data to use the iteration ?